# What does "divided highway" written on a white regulatory sign mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, legalese

When it appears on a regulatory sign, what it means and what should I do, is the thing I have a great deal of difficulty with.

This is one of those signs I came across - **Divided Highway.**

What does it mean?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regulations/law. Incorrect or misapplied Answers to such questions could cause legal or physical harm. (As read by anyone, at any time in the future, who may live anywhere.)

Comment: Please add more context. The country it's in, what the road around the sign looks like, etc. A picture would be great if you have one.

Answer (score 3):

Divided highway is a type of highway wherein traffic travels in the opposite directions and the highway is separated by some line, lawn or construction. And I think, in most of the countries, it's the same.

[MW describes it:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divided%20highway)

> Divided Highway - a highway of four or more traffic lanes having two roadways with a median strip between them separating opposing traffic streams

[image]

It's also known as a dual carriageway or dual highway